# specified cast is not valid VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Im having trouble with the following subroutine.

Its purpose is to find a value (in this case a date), and compare it with `todaysdate`. if an istance of the date was found in `DateAscending`, then `dateexists` is set to true.

The error "'Specified Cast is not valid'" is displayed when the if statement is executed.

I have used the same routine before, to find a username which was a string, `todaysdate` however is a `date` - so im 99% sure the problem is to do with the datatype, but i dont know how to resolve it.

the vairibale `getconn` holds the connection string.

`tablename` is a string with the correct table name.

```
        Dim todaysdate As Date = Today
        Dim dateexists As Boolean = False
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection(getconn)
            connection.Open()
            Dim sql = "SELECT DateAscending FROM " & tablename
            Dim finddate As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = finddate.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                If todaysdate = CDate(reader.GetString(0)) Then 'Error occurs here
                    dateexists = True
                End If
            End While
            reader.Close()
            connection.Close()
      End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do the string representations of your dates in column 0 look like? It seems like the string cannot be converted to a date.

Also this task should be done by a SELECT COUNT(*) Statement like this:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " & tablename
sql &= " WHERE DateAscending ='" & Strings.Format(todaysdate, "YourFormat") & "'"

Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
dateexists = CInt(Cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0
```

Replace "YourFormat" with the format your dates are formatted in this column. You will find some examples for the Format function here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The columnname is DateAscending. they are all in the format **/**/****, and the data type of the column is Date/Time. All the values are input into the table as a vb date in the first place.

Comment: What about trying reader.GetDateTime method instead of GetString?

Comment: If you want to use the SELECT COUNT(*) statement, the format would be "\#yyyy-MM-dd\#" for MS Access and "\'yyyy-MM-dd\'" for the SQL Server. For other Datebase Servers there would be a similar format string. But important: You have to omit the ' around your parameter, because its not a string, its a time literal.

Comment: So the second line would read liks this for Access:
sql &= " WHERE DateAscending = " & Strings.Format(todaysdate, "\#yyyy-MM-dd\#")

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've eddited reader.GetString(0) to reader.GetDateTime(0) and it works perfectly. It makes sense to me now, and ill keep it in mind.